# What is the best way to do noise filtering for speech applications in matlab?

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, noise-reduction

My speech is sampled at F=44100Hz. Each sample is recorded for 2.5 seconds (2500 milliseconds). I wish to filter out all noise, without affecting the data much.
I have recorded the samples in .wav format, and I'm using Matlab for noise filtering. Noise in my samples is basic noise i.e. very very little from traffic, some for rotating fan, minute movements, breathing, some from microphone, and any basic form of noise in generally silent environment.

Which noise filtering technique/(s) should I use?
Should I use multiple noise filtering techniques? If so, which ones do I use? And in what order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Plot the power spectrum in time or spectrogram of your audio signal and identify the frequency band corresponding to the voice signal. A bandpass filter might be suitable to filter out the background noise and the fan component.